# Need some good organic modeling/topology tutorials for character creation

Tags: modeling, topology

As the title says, where can I find some really good tutorials about organic modeling? I know how to use Blender and model stuff, but I want to get into character modeling now and I have trouble creating good topology for face/hands/etc. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try Blenderella and Darren Lile videos; or Ben Simonds and Tony Mullen Books?

Comment: Sorry, I don't think tutorial requests are on topic for blender SE.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for tutorials, which is out side this sites scope. See point 1 [here](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/6/2217).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the add-on retopoflow. You can get the plugin as well as the tutorial on how to use it here.
                                                       Download  add-on:https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow

Tutorial: https://cgcookie.com/course/introduction-to-retopoflow/